# How to align form with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a facebook clone of the sign in page. I am stuck on the nav. I want to input, label to align to the flex-end but I am not sure how.

I have tried to use justify-content on the div. But it dosent-work. I have tried justify-content on the nav but I want only the form and button to align to the right and not the h1 fakebook.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#main-header #nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #4f43b9;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0.3rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  background: #6b5eda;
  border: 1px solid #1f166e;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #291d8f;
}
```

```
CSS3
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#main-header #nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #4f43b9;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0.3rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  background: #6b5eda;
  border: 1px solid #1f166e;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #291d8f;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `margin-left: auto;`, but without the HTML it's hard to tell.

Here is the fiddle, with what I assumed the markup is based on the classes in the CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/b7f3xdao/

Again, it's hard to say what is causing the wrong display if there isn't any HTML.

Here's the snippet:

```css
body {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#main-header #nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #4f43b9;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0.3rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  background: #6b5eda;
  border: 1px solid #1f166e;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #291d8f;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main-header">
    <div id="nav-bar">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="btn">
        Button
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you put the fiddle code on a StackOverflow snippet so it can be run on here, it'll be easier for people to see what you did :)